How do I use WolframAlpha to get Initial Values to numerically solve Bessel Function through Runge Kutta?
I have to code the Runge-Kutta Method to solve a Bessel Function of the first kind. Here are some excerpts from the instructions of my assignment:

For the initial conditions go to WolframAlpha and,

To eliminate the constant $c_2$ from equation
$$
y(x) = c_1 J_\alpha (x) + c_2 Y_\alpha (x) 
$$
(General solution to the Bessel equation), you must choose one of the zeros of the Bessel function using the function BesselJZero[n, k], where $n$ is the desired value (I'm given $n = 3.2$), and $k$ is the $k$th zero of the Bessel function.

To choose $c_1 = 1$, use the function BesselJ[n,x] to select the value of the function at some desired $x$-value.


This procedure will leave the $J_a(x)$ desired function. Don't forget to report the values used.

Questions:
I don’t understand how this procedure provides me with the initial values (i.e., the value of the function at a starting point and the value of its first derivative). Should I separate the second-order equation into a system of first-order equations?
Should I also use DSolve from WolframAlpha?
Thank you so much in advance!

I mean yeah, but the thing is that i need to use WolframAlpha cause idk it's part of my assignment

The problem belongs on Mathematica.SE
